# How to write a multiline?

Tags: brackets, multline

I want to write this

[image]

I tryed this:

```
\begin{multline}
  W^{m ,\Phi}(\Omega)= \bigl\{u\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega); ~\text{there exists}~ \{g_{\alpha}\}\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega), \alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N), ~\text{such that}\\
\int_{\Omega}u\frac{\partial^{\alpha}\varphi}{\partial ^{\alpha_1}x_1\ldots\partial^{\alpha_N}x_N}dx=(-1)^{||\alpha||_{S}}\int_{\Omega}g_{\alpha}\varphi dx,\\
\text{for any}~ \varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)~\text{and}~ ||\alpha||_{S}\leq m  \bigr\}\nonumber
\end{multline}
```

but I'd like to get "for any" under the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want `align` rather than `multline`. However, such long set descriptions should be avoided, because they are really difficult to read.

Note a few fixes. Avoid `~` in math mode: adding the space in `\text` is often better. I added `\,` in front of `dx`, which is good practice. For the norm, `||` is incorrect: `\lVert` and `\rVert` should be used as done below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{First solution}

Here is a long set description
\begin{align*}
W^{m ,\Phi}(\Omega)=
\Bigl\{
u\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega);
& \text{ there exists } \{g_{\alpha}\}\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega),
  \alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_N), \text{ such that}
\\
&\int_{\Omega}
  u\frac{\partial^{\alpha}\varphi}
        {\partial^{\alpha_1}x_1\dots\partial^{\alpha_N}x_N}\,dx
=(-1)^{\|\alpha\|_{S}}\int_{\Omega}g_{\alpha}\varphi \,dx,
\\
&\text{for any } \varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)
\text{ and } \lVert\alpha\rVert_{S}\leq m \Bigr\}
\end{align*}
but, as you see, it is difficult to read.

\section{Second solution}

We denote by $W^{m ,\Phi}(\Omega)$ the set consisting
of all $u\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega)$ for which there exists
$\{g_{\alpha}\}\in L^{\Phi}(\Omega)$, with
$\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_N)$, such that
\[
\int_{\Omega}
  u\frac{\partial^{\alpha}\varphi}
        {\partial^{\alpha_1}x_1\dots\partial^{\alpha_N}x_N}\,dx
=(-1)^{\lVert\alpha\rVert_{S}}\int_{\Omega}g_{\alpha}\varphi \,dx,
\]
for any $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ and $\|\alpha\|_{S}\leq m$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want to align something, you should use some environment which would allow you that. It can be `{align}` or `{split}`. Since this formula represents a single equation, I'd suggest `{split}`. Also, I think that it's better not to use many `\text{}`s but use ordinary math mode inside one `\text{}`. Also, `\Vert` gives better spacing than `||`. And I took the liberty of removing unnecessary braces, as the code is more readable without them. And the last: there were many typos (`\varphi` in place of `\psi`, missing `_` etc.). Currently, I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
W^m L_\Phi(\Omega)
  =\biggl\{u\in L_\Phi(\Omega)\colon\
    &\text{there exists $\{g_{\alpha}\}\in L_\Phi(\Omega)$,
                         $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_N)$, such that}\\
    &\int_\Omega u\frac{\partial^\alpha\psi}{\partial^{\alpha_1}x_1\ldots\partial^{\alpha_N}x_N}dx
      =(-1)^{\Vert\alpha\Vert_S}\int_\Omega g_\alpha\psi dx,\\
    &\text{for any $\psi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\Vert\alpha\Vert_S\leq m$}\biggr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: I've fixed alignment a bit.